# Laravel echo custom error message when form action happens

Tags: php, laravel, validation

The goal is if a specific card # is used the order submits and saves to the database (this part is working). However, if you put in a different specific number it should print "Your card has been declined" I can't get this part to work I am getting error Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Session' not found

Controller Use

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Item;
use App\Purchase;
use App\Http\Controllers\Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Controller Function

```
public function store(Purchase $purchase, Item $item)
{
  $this->validate(request(), [
  'fName' => 'required|min:3',
  'lName' => 'required|min:3',
  'address' => 'required',
  'city' => 'required',
  'state' => 'required',
  'zip' => 'required',
  'card' => ['required', 'regex:(5105 1051 0510 5100|4111 1111 1111 1111)']
  ]);

  $purchase->product = request('product');
  $purchase->fName = request('fName');
  $purchase->lName = request('lName');
  $purchase->address = request('address');
  $purchase->city = request('city');
  $purchase->state = request('state');
  $purchase->zip = request('zip');
  $purchase->card = request('card');

  if (request('card') == '5105 1051 0510 5100') {
    $purchase->save(); // Save to the database
    return redirect('/thanks/'.$item->id);
  } elseif (request('card') == '4111 1111 1111 1111') {
    Session::flash('error', "Special message goes here");
    return Redirect::back();
  }

  return back();
}
```

Edit now that it is working I am not getting the actual message to print.

Blade

```
@php
  if ( Session::has('error') ) {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-info">{{ Session::get("error") }}</div>';
  }
@endphp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the backslash

```
\Session::flash('error', "Special message goes here");
^^
```

Or replace

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Session;
```

With

```
use Session;
```

If you take a look at `config/app.php` you will see some aliases there.

And fix your code here:

```
@php
  if ( Session::has('error') ) {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-info">'. Session::get("error") . '</div>';
  }
@endphp
```

Comment: Awesome that is what I was missing. Quick question now that it's working it is printing "{{ Session::get("error") }}" instead of the actual error. Any ideas what I might be missing? I'll update my question with the blade.

Comment: I swear I tried that and it didn't work haha thanks dude! It worked when I tried.